# What is the order of installation for a stair railing?

Tags: installation, stairs, railing

I am rebuilding a set of steps, and have decided that I need to replace the handrail at the base of the steps.  This is one of the exposed handrails, with ballisters and a newel at the end.  This is a straight run - no curves and no angle changes.  From what I understand, there are basically 4 different parts - the shoe, the ballisters (the upright supports), the newel (the post at the end) and the handrail.  In what order should I install the parts?  Should I fit the Newel in before the shoe to ensure a tight miter cut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wickes (UK DIY store) sells stair packs and has general fitting instructions.

These are available [on-line](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Good-Idea-Leaflets/Stairparts/pcat/30stairparts). They are too long to summarise here, but do take you through the process step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Another resource is LJ Smith which sells stair parts. Their main site is:

http://ljsmith.com/

They have a much more complex set of installation instructions that include landings, turns, balcony railings, open and closed stair treads, etc. Check it out:

http://ljsmith.com/assets/files/pdf/EnglishInstallation.pdf